# Can't remove '+' sign from filenames using powershell

Tags: powershell, shell

I have bunch of files containing + sign in their name this script runs for removing any substring and character when doesn't work for '+' sign

`Get-ChildItem -Recurse '*.*' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '+','' }` 
Please help

I tried to remove '+' sign from filenames

Comment: PowerShell's `-replace` operator is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based. Regex _metacharacters_ (those with special meaning), namely `\ ( ) | . * + ? ^ $ [ {`, need to be ``\``-_escaped_ in order to be used _verbatim_; escape whole strings with `[regex]::Escape()`. Alternatively, use the `[string]` type's `.Replace()` method for verbatim replacements, but note that it is case-_sensitive_, _invariably_ in Windows PowerShell, and _by default_ in PowerShell (Core) 6+. See the linked duplicate for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` sign has a special meaning in [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions?view=powershell-7.3), if you want to match it literally using `-replace`, the same needs to be escaped:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse '*+*.*' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -Replace '\+' }
```

Or use a [literal replacement method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-7.0) instead:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse '*+*.*' |
    Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name.Replace('+', '') }
```